# show what package module is from

Tags: python

i'm running a number of different linux's as virtual machines and am trying to write a python program that is cross distro able.

what i'm trying to figure out is, when i try to import something on one machine it can do different things than the same package on others.  all have been installed from pip/pip3.  i'm trying to find out what specific package the imported package/modules are from.

i.e->

```
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=24

Python 3.5.1

>>> from systemd import journal
```

no errors

```
ID=debian
stretch/sid

Python 3.5.2

>>> from systemd import journal

ImportError: cannot import name 'journal'
```

this happens on other os's also.

and once i'm in the python interpreter and do 'help(systemd)' i get differing results also.

how can i know what pip package the fedora systemd is from.  i really don't feel like installing all of it's pip packages to hope that it works.

both version of what i think it is from are the same, python-systemd 0.0.9

i have searched and all i can find is to find what modules are in what packages, not how to know what it's installed from.

thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about the version? [`stretch` has a different version](https://packages.debian.org/testing/python-systemd) than [the one that ships with fedora 24](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/python-systemd) which might explain the issue.

Comment: when doing pip list, i get different values.  when doing pip search systemd i get the same version that is installed as latest.

Comment: Maybe need check output on terminal  `lsb_release -a` before calling special module. OR `import systemd: all_key = systemd.__builtins__.keys(); if your_key_in all_key : #do what you want`